# t5-fresh-editor-stylesheets.php breaks image placement in WP Beta 3 editor

Tags: images, css, editor

I am running a development site with the WordPress beta plugin, currently running 3.9 beta 3

I am using Bill Erickson's Core functionality plugin which calls Toscho's t5-fresh-editor-stylesheets.php code "Enforces fresh editor stylesheets per version parameter"

Updating to the beta I notice that when inserting an image in the post editor, the edit screen does not show the edit/delete icons, nor is it positioned correctly when choosing an alignment. The image however is displayed correctly on the preview page.

I am not much of a coder, however I guessed this is a TinyMCE CSS problem, I disabled all plugins however and the image placement in the editor was corrected and the image icons reappeared.

I traced the problem to the t5-fresh-editor-stylesheets.php code  - commenting out the call to this page fixed the problem.

Any chance of a fix Toscho? Please forgive me if this is the wrong place to post this request.

Comment: I will take look this evening.